# doctrine 2 many to many relation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm creating my Doctrine 2 mappings (in XML). I would like to create a many-to-many relationship between the entities Snippet and Tag using:

**Snippet**:

```
<many-to-many field="tags" target-entity="Tag">
    <cascade><cascade-all /></cascade>
</many-to-many>
```

**Tag**

```
<many-to-many field="snippets" target-entity="Snippet">
    <cascade><cascade-all /></cascade>
</many-to-many>
```

However when I use the schematool to generate my database tables, two tables are added. tag_snippet and snippet_tag. Is there any way to use only 1 table instead of 2?

A solution would be only defining the relation in one of the entities but will I be able to access it from the other one? (because no specific property is defined the other way around)

Looks like I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to decide which is the "owning side" (in Doctrine parlance), and add the appropriate "mapped-by" and "inversed-by" attributes to  your ManyToMany tags.

See the [documenation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional), specifically the XML example.